# Integrated Windows Authentication - Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

I am attempting to use Integrated Windows Authentication on IIS for an MVC web app. The original hope was that the user would be logged in automatically using the current Windows user credentials. I am running into the issue where the user is always prompted to enter user name and password. I have decided that we can live with this. However, I have also noticed that the user can enter any valid domain credentials...it's not limited to the currently logged in machine. But if this is the case, I need to provide a logout button, so the user can be switched if necessary.

Everything I can find on this issue, logging out in Windows Authentication, says you cannot do it because it pulls the credentials from the machine login. But it's obviously not doing that in my case, because I can enter any valid credentials and log in successfully. So a user could be logged onto the machine as user X, and then, when prompted, log into the web app as user Y. Am I to understand that, under Windows Authentication, there's no way to address this?

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup.  Using windows auth should be seamless.

Comment: Chrome and IE should be seamless.  [FireFox will not pass NTLM credentials by default](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/firefox-how-to-enable-automatic-ntlm-authentication/)

Comment: IIS Windows authentication has no logout option, and you cannot switch users. So when you described that above, it seems to be forms authentication.

Comment: You need to add your app to the browsers 'Trusted Sites'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you selected Windows Authentication While creating the Project? Confirm that and if yes, proceed to check your web.config that application authentication is set to windows.